# How to write to Sql server from MapBasic and insert rows

Tags: sql, query, mapbasic, server

I have created a table in Sql server 2014 with the columns: Id (int), Geom (geometry), RouteId (int), Desc (varchar(MAX))
I have succeeded in making the table mappable through MapInfo
I have checked .TAB file for the table, that it has IsReadOnly = false

Stil when i try to execute an insert query on the table I get the error messsage that the table is read only. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Also I cannot figure out how to write a correct insert query I have tried doing that on a copied version of the table code is as follows

```
Dim rId As Integer
Dim oPline as Object
rId = 20
Dim t As String
t = "test"
Create pline into variable oPline 2 (1,2)(1,3)

Insert into TestGeom1 (Geom, RouteId, Desc) VALUES (oPline, rId, t)
```

Writing like above I get the error messsage field Geom does not exist in table TestGeom1
If i replace Geom with obj or just remove it completely i get the error Expression does not evaluate to a column or a table name.
So please who can tell me what is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have specified a unique primary key in the table in SQL Server. Also you could take advantage of the IDENTITY type so that you don't have to manage the ID's yourself.
2. Make sure your text columns are defined as varchar and that they aren't wider than 254. Otherwise you might have an issue editing the data
3. Once the table is opened in MapInfo Professional your spatial column is always called OBJ. So use this insert statement:

   Insert into TestGeom1 (OBJ, RouteId, Desc) VALUES (oPline, rId, t)

If you have a statement that works in the MapBasic window but doesn't work in the MapBasic application, you should have a look at your variable and function names. Maybe you have a variable using the same name as a table or column.

Also try to create the table in the database from MapInfo Professional using File > New, when specifying the location of the table, pick an open connection to your database. In this way you can create a new table directly in your database

If you use the Per Row Style option, the width of the column might prevnet you from editing the object. If the column is wider than 254, MapInfo Pro can't edit the column and so the spatial object also gets read-only

Comment: I am using identity in sql server problem there however is that the table is readonly when opened in MapInfo I dont know how to gain write access.

Comment: Just to get on with it I have tried using Save copy as in MapInfo. And continue working on the copied table it is possible to write to that one I have tried drawing directly in the map window that works fine. Writing the exact query you suggested gives the error Expression does not evaluate to a column or a table name I have tried with only Id, RouteId fields that executes in the MapBasic window but executing from my mapbasic program I get the error message above again

Comment: My unique primary key is the Id (int) field and i am using the IDENTITY type on that one.

Comment: Oh, you have set the Desc column to the maximum width. MapInfo Professional can only write to it if it is 254 characters or less. Change it and reopen the table from the database

Comment: Ok I will try that I only added the column because MapInfo asks for a character typed column when it makes the table mappable but it does not tell anything about what length is needed

Comment: I have tried it and it solved the readonly issue. But I still get the same error message when trying to run my insert statement. I am using a project file dont know if that might have an affect on it. I ran the insert statment on the sql server table now since that is the one I want to use.

Comment: I have tried making the geom field nullable and running a simple statement like this: Insert into TestGeom (RouteId) VALUES (2) it works in the MapBasic window inside MapInfo but not when run from a MapBasic program. TestGeom is the sql server table TestGeom1 was the copied table

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Expression does not evaluate to a column or a table name

Comment: How does the statement look? Are you sure you have spelled the table name and column names correctly?

Comment: Thats the weird thing I copied this statement from the MapBasic program into the MapBasic window in MapInfo to be sure everything is the same but one place it works and the other not. Of course this is not what I want in the end currently I am just trying get something into the database right now there is nothing more to it than following: Insert into TestGeom (RouteId) VALUES (2)

Comment: Now just for testing it i created a new table in Sql Server same structure without the geometry field on that one the query executes without any trouble so as far I can see it has something to do with the object column I executed following from the MapBasic program and it worked fine: Insert into Test (Nr, Tekst) VALUES (4, "tttt")
 Commit Table Test Interactive

Comment: I have added a few things that can be wrong in my answer above

Comment: Turned out I had a naming conflict as suggested in the answer. This is something I will keep in mind another time.